# Item in list multiplied by delta_time not showing change on screen

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, timedelta

I created a class that handles particles in pygame. In the emit function which moves and displays the particles, I also have it set to gradually darken each particle. It darkens each particle but very minimally. This is because somehow the color of each particle, stored in a list with the particle's other data, is only changed by a small amount. For example, its default value is (255, 255, 255), after a single darken, it becomes around (245, 245, 245). It should continue to darken, but it just stops instead. When I change the other values of the particle, like its position, they don't reset, and each particle has its own list of values, so I have no idea why it is resetting. Here is part of the code(inside a class):

```
def emit(self, screen, delta_time):
    if self.particles:  # If there is anything in the particles list:
        self.null_particles()  # Delete all faded particles from list
        for particle in self.particles:  # Loop through all particles in list
                        # Shift particle spawn location
            particle[0][0] += random.randint(-20, 20)
            particle[0][1] += random.randint(-10, 10)

            # If the direction isn't set, make it random
            if particle[2] == [0, 0]:
                particle[2] = [random.randint(-3, 3), random.randint(-3, 3)]
            elif particle[2][0] == 0:
                particle[2][0] = random.randint(-3, 3)
            elif particle[2][1] == 0:
                particle[2][1] = random.randint(-3, 3)

            # Move particle based off of direction parameters
            particle[0][0] += particle[2][0]
            particle[0][1] += particle[2][1]

            # Make particle smaller (fade out effect)
            particle[1] -= 50*delta_time

        # Make color gradually get darker
            proxy_color = (particle[3][0]-10*delta_time, particle[3][1]-10*delta_time, particle[3][2]-10*delta_time)
            if proxy_color[0] < 0 or proxy_color[1] < 0 or proxy_color[2] < 0:
                pass
            else:
                particle[3] = proxy_color
            # Display particle
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, particle[3], particle[0], int(particle[1]))

def add_particles(self, pos_x, pos_y, direction_x=0, direction_y=0, color=(255, 255, 255)):
    pos_x = pos_x
    pos_y = pos_y
    radius = 7
    particle_circle = [[pos_x, pos_y], radius, [direction_x, direction_y], color]
    self.particles.append(particle_circle)

def null_particles(self):
    particle_copy = [particle for particle in self.particles if particle[1] > 0]
    self.particles = particle_copy

def delete_particles(self):
    self.particles = []
```

Next part, inside a player class, where the particle object is being used:

```
def particle_display(self, screen, delta_time):
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.time_jumping <= 200:  # While player jumped within less than .2 seconds ago:
        dust_particle.add_particles(self.rect.midbottom[0], self.ground_level, 0, -10)  # Add more particles
        dust_particle.add_particles(self.rect.midbottom[0], self.ground_level, 0, -10)  # Add more particles
        dust_particle.add_particles(self.rect.midbottom[0], self.ground_level, 0, -10)  # Add more particles

        dust_particle.emit(screen, delta_time)  # Display said particles
    else:
        # Delay added to give particles time to disperse, so particles dont get deleted when buttons get deleted
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.jump_ended >= 200:
            # Delete all particles after .2 sec of jump, or before jumping happened
            dust_particle.delete_particles()
```

The above code, inside a player class, is called in an update method inside the class. This update method is called in a while 1 loop(infinite game loop).

Particle[3] (particles color data), is never manually (or purposefully), reset by me.

Sample output when particle[3] (the part of the list that stores the color) is printed:

> Blockquote
> (253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006)
> (253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006)
> (253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006, 253.68000000000006)
> (253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005)
> (253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005)
> (253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005, 253.85000000000005)
> (254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004)
> (254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004)
> (254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004, 254.02000000000004)
> (254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003)
> (254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003)
> (254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003, 254.19000000000003)
> (254.36, 254.36, 254.36)
> (254.36, 254.36, 254.36)
> (254.36, 254.36, 254.36)
> (254.52, 254.52, 254.52)
> (254.52, 254.52, 254.52)
> (254.52, 254.52, 254.52)
> (254.68, 254.68, 254.68)
> (254.68, 254.68, 254.68)
> (254.68, 254.68, 254.68)
> (254.84, 254.84, 254.84)
> (254.84, 254.84, 254.84)
> (254.84, 254.84, 254.84)
> (255, 255, 255)
> (255, 255, 255)
> (255, 255, 255)

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like `delta_time` is `-0.017`.  Is that possible?  That would produce the results you see, with the components going up by 0.17 each time.

Comment: where do you update particles? I see only that you create or delete them but I don't see where you move and change color.

Comment: Inside the particle class. particle[0][0] += particle[2][0]
            particle[0][1] += particle[2][1. Also, The delta_time is consistently .017, I  figured out the issue, the value I was multiplying by delta_time to darken the color was too low, I ramped up the value, and it worked. (How do i mark as answered?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, as with many other things related to delta_time. If something doesn't work as expected, simply raise the value you are multiplying by delta_time, as when you multiply by delta_time, it makes the change over time consistent at different frame rates, but it is a consistently smaller change than before on the same frame rate with delta_time.

In this case, all I had to do was lower the value from -10 to -800.
So : `proxy_color = (particle[3][0]-10*delta_time, particle[3][1]-10*delta_time, particle[3][2]-10*delta_time)` -> `proxy_color = (particle[3][0]-800*delta_time, particle[3][1]-800*delta_time, particle[3][2]-800*delta_time)`